# increase and decrease date

Tags: asp.net

I want to increase and decrease date on image button click.e.g. < 10/11/09 >.
how can i do that???

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to code is with two regular buttons and (server side) code behind.
Read the date from the input field, AddDays(1) or AddDays(-1) and rewrite that input field.

A more user-friendly way would use client-side javascript.

See also for example the Ajax Toolkit Library that adds a (client side) calendar selector to a TextBox. See http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx .

Answer (score 1):

In the button click event get the date, create a new instance with the AddDays, AddMonths method etc., then set the text back as necessary.